# Best way to manage the ActiveWorkbook in a VSTO Excel Addin application

Tags: .net, excel, vsto

I've developed a rather intensive Excel Addin (VTSO based) that creates an in-memory datatable from  database query, and then binds this to ListObject.  There are a bunch of other functions available when this ListObject is created (including event handlers that update calculations in the datatable, and custom task panes that popout to show additional information about a cell).

The Addin works well, although I'm getting issues when users open other Excel workbooks or additional instances of Excel to multi-task on work.

What's the best way to manage the state of this particular application?  Users should only ever work on one copy of this workbook at a time, however the flexibility of Excel makes it difficult to manage.

How do others manage this?  I was thinking of creating a GUID when a workbook is created, and then testing for this whenever code is called to make sure that the active workbook is the correct workbook.  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you shouldn't force users to only work with a single workbook.

For excel 2013 and higher, you should maintain a reference to all workbooks that are open (in a dictionary for instance). Every time a new workbook is activate/deactivate you need to update those references. You can use the integer `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Hwnd` that correspond to the unique top level windows handle as a key for your dictionary. You can attach each key to a class that correspond to the state of your application, every times the workbook activate/deactivate event is fired you need to update those states.

In other words, you should attach the setting of your application (database connection ...) to workbooks thanks to `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Hwnd`, no need to use a GUID.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24732000/3205529) for reference.

Comment: Thanks @Malick.  Sounds like a good approach.  Given the flexible nature of Excel, I'm concerned about ensuring that the user only impacts the correct workbook via the addin as I can see big problems otherwise.  Managing the task panes are also a concern.  Thanks for your thoughts!