# Trouble attaching an event to a custom task pane. VSTO, Excel 2016

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

### **Background**

I'm currently working on an application in VSTO2015 and Excel 2016. The application manages a number of CustomTaskPanes in different windows. I am trying to get `// some code` to fire when the task pane is opened or closed. In order to handle the various windows, I've implemented a structure very similar to this;

[CustomTaskPane in Excel doesn't appear in new Workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160158/customtaskpane-in-excel-doesnt-appear-in-new-workbooks/24732000?noredirect=1#comment56674407_24732000)

`ThisAddIn.cs` contains the following class;

```
public class TaskPaneManager
    {
        static Dictionary<string, Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane> _createdPanes = new Dictionary<string, Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the taskpane by name (if exists for current excel window then returns existing instance, otherwise uses taskPaneCreatorFunc to create one). 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="taskPaneId">Some string to identify the taskpane</param>
        /// <param name="taskPaneTitle">Display title of the taskpane</param>
        /// <param name="taskPaneCreatorFunc">The function that will construct the taskpane if one does not already exist in the current Excel window.</param>
        public static Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane GetTaskPane(string taskPaneId, string taskPaneTitle, Func<UserControl> taskPaneCreatorFunc)
        {
            string key = string.Format("{0}({1})", taskPaneId, Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Hwnd);
            string title = taskPaneId;
            string windowId = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Hwnd.ToString();

            if (!_createdPanes.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                var customTaskPane = taskPaneCreatorFunc();
                var pane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(customTaskPane, taskPaneTitle);
                _createdPanes[key] = pane;

                //
                // Set the task pane width as set in the App.Config
                //
                pane.Width = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TaskPaneWidth"]);
            }
            return _createdPanes[key];
        }
    ....
```

My calls from `Ribbon.cs`;

```
private void btnUploadWizard_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    // Check for configuration sheet first.

    string title = "Upload Wizard";

    TaskPaneManager.isConfigurationCreated();

    var UploadWizardTaskpane = TaskPaneManager.GetTaskPane(title, title, () => new TaskPaneUploadWizard());
    UploadWizardTaskpane.Visible = !UploadWizardTaskpane.Visible;

}
```

### **The Problem: Event Handlers**

I'm having difficulty getting an event handler to fire. I can't tell what I'm doing wrong. In the `TaskPaneDesigner` I am attaching the event using `this.VisibleChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.TaskPaneUploadWizard_VisibleChanged);`, and then defining it in my `TaskPaneUploadWizard` class as follows;

```
public partial class TaskPaneUploadWizard : UserControl
{
    ...

    public TaskPaneUploadWizard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TaskPaneUploadWizard_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Some code
    }
```

### **My thoughts**

It seems to me as though I am either attaching the eventHandler to something other than the `CustomTaskPane` object, or I am attaching it before the `CustomTaskPane` is created.

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect if the task pane was opened or closed, you have to attach to the `VisibleChanged` event of `pane`.

So the simplest solution would be to add just one line of code to the `GetTaskPane` method:

```
var pane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(customTaskPane, taskPaneTitle);
// This is the new line to be added.
pane.VisibleChanged += (s, e) => customTaskPane.Visible = pane.Visible;
_createdPanes[key] = pane;
```

Now the visibility of the whole task pane will be passed on to its content and `// some code` should be executed.

Alternatively, if you don't want to manually set `customTaskPane.Visible` for whatever reason, you could as well execute your code directly in this new event handler:

```
pane.VisibleChanged += (s, e) => { /* some code */ };
```

But personally I would rather recommend the first approach because it seems to fit a bit better into your existing code.

Comment: @user3465779 You're welcome, glad I could help you!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var UploadWizardTaskpane = TaskPaneManager.GetTaskPane(title, title, () => new TaskPaneUploadWizard());
```

This is creating a `CustomTaskPane` not a `TaskPaneUploadWizard` object

It seems like `this.VisibleChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.TaskPaneUploadWizard_VisibleChanged);` is acting on `TaskPaneUploadWizard` which is only the guest of `CustomTaskPane`

**Note that** The visibility of `CustomTaskPane` doesn't affect `TaskPaneUploadWizard`

### My suggestion

You remove `VisibleChanged` from the designer, you will add it manually in your `TaskPaneUploadWizard`

```
public partial class TaskPaneUploadWizard : UserControl
{
    //{---}
    CustomTaskPane _HostPane;
    public CustomTaskPane HostPane
    {
         get => _HostPane;
         set
         {
             if(_HostPane == value)
                 return;
             _HostPane?.VisibleChanged -= TaskPaneUploadWizard_VisibleChanged;
             _HostPane = value;
             _HostPane?.VisibleChanged += TaskPaneUploadWizard_VisibleChanged;
         }
    }
    //{---}
    private void TaskPaneUploadWizard_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Some code
    }
    //{---}
```

Then in `GetTaskPane` you say

```
//{---}
var pane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(customTaskPane, taskPaneTitle);
(customTaskPane as TaskPaneUploadWizard).HostPane = pane;
//{---}
```